# Get file or image path as string from uid

Tags: 7, files

I need to get the relative path to a file, in this case, what i need is:

/sites/default/files/pics/DSC00873_39.JPG

But all I seem to be able to get is the following:

```
$file = file_load($pic);
print $file->uri; // public://pics/DSC00873_39.JPG
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: I don't get it. What does the UID have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. There is a function for that.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7

Comment: yep, return file_create_url($file->uri);